# How to make Zend Framework error page to look more clearly and beautifully?

Tags: php, zend-framework

By default error page in ZF looks like this:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Form_Exception' with message 'Method setDeault does not exist' in /usr/home/.../library/Zend/Form.php:2838 
Stack trace: 
#0 [internal function]: Zend_Form->__call('setDeault', Array) 
#1 /usr/home/.../application/admin/controllers/TagsController.php(40): Web_Form_Admintags->setDeault('tagstext', '....') 
#2 /usr/home/.../library/Zend/
```

Is there any ways to change this messy error description to more clearly form (something like Django error page)?

Comment: For extended exception dump I suggest using Nette\Debugger (http://translate.google.com/translate?u=http%3A%2F%2Fdoc.nette.org%2Fcs%2Fdebugging&ie=UTF8&sl=cs&tl=en)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an error page but a standard PHP output for uncaught exceptions. As far as I know there is no default error page in Zend Framework -- you will have to create your own by creating an appropriate view for the ErrorController.

Answer (score 1):

AFAICR this is using the Error controller right? That message is basically the dump of the [exception object](http://www.php.net/exception). You can split this up by calling different parts individually rather than dumping the whole lot as a string. See the manual page I linked to.

Make sure you're only providing exception information when the `APPLICATION_ENVIRONMENT` is set to `development` as well.

Answer (score 0):

The exception is formatted using new lines, which are however not transformed to 
 in html.
You have several options...

1. Wrap the error with `<pre></pre>` tags
2. Create custom exception handler

```
function exception_handler($exception) {
  echo "Uncaught exception: " , $exception->getMessage(), "\n";
}

set_exception_handler('exception_handler');
```